# Javascript RegExp replace text between two tags if the opening tag has specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regexp-replace

I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text AAA</span>
```

I want to replace the text between the span tags, but only if the span tag has the class "**search-text**". So in my case, I have a string containing an HTML code with two spans. I want to replace the text from the second span if it contains a searched text.

I search for: "**aa**" and I want to replace it with `<span class="highlight-text">aa</span>`. So the final result should be:

```
<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text <span class="highlight-search">AA</span>A</span>
```

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
var paint = $.proxy(this._paint, this);
var regex = /(<span class="search-text[^>]+>|<\/span>)/g;
item.node.innerHTML = item.html.replace(regex, paint);
```

where "**value**" is: "**aa**" and "**item.html**" is the HTML presented at the beginning of my question.

the _paint function:

```
_paint: function($0) {
   return '<span class="highlight-text">' + $0 + '</span>';
},
```

At this moment the result is that the second span is entirely wrapped into the `'<span class="highlight-text">' + $0 + '</span>';` . This is the result:

```
<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="highlight-text"><span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text AAA</span></span>
```

I want only the text match to be wrapped inside the hghlight span, like this:

```
<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text <span class="highlight-text">AA</span>A</span>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to create a document fragment, put the HTML text in there, and then use ordinary DOM APIs to find and manipulate the HTML. Working on HTML with regular expressions is a mess.

Comment: [You really don't want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: If this is *already* the page code, then you probably don't even need a document fragment. Otherwise, if you have an HTML string, then you can do that. A regex would be *ugly*. What if `search-text` is the *second* class? Or third? What if the `class` attribute is not even the first one in the element?

Comment: I'm not manipulating the DOM, I already have an array with all items. The array contains the items text and items html.

Comment: It'd still probably be easier to convert those into a doc fragment and use DOM tools on them than to try to regex against the many possible variations HTML allows.  But if you show that array, so we can see what you're actually working with, you might get better answers

Comment: I'm trying to integrate your solution. I'll get back in a few minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is [notoriously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) the wrong tool for most of this job; it's designed for manipulating strings, not structured data such as HTML. Fortunately, you're already in the browser, so you have an entire toolset designed for DOM manipulation available: may as well use it.  (You've also tagged the question with jQuery, which makes it even easier.)

*Update: I'd misread a detail in the question, and was pulling the search string from a parent node's attribute instead of externally; I also failed to make the search case-insensitive.  Both now corrected in the below:*

```js
// Make a case-insensitive regex from the search string
let str = 'aa';
let re = new RegExp(str, "gi");

// operate only on the .search-text nodes:
$('.search-text').each(function(i, el) {
  // get the current contents of the element:
  let text = $(el).html();

  // Add your highlights:
  text = text.replace(re, '<span class="highlight-text">$&</span>');

  // insert the modified text back into the DOM:
  $(el).html(text);
})
```

```css
.highlight-text {
  background-color: #FFC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text AAA</span> I
```

This is only really safe if the  `.search-text` elements have no child nodes.  It will *generally* work even if they contain some HTML, but only if:

- You're certain that the strings you're highlighting will never match portions of the HTML itself, and
- there aren't any event bindings attached to the DOM elements (this script replaces the contents of `.search-text` wholesale.)

For example, trying to highlight the word "span" in an html string containing `<span>` elements would result in invalid html:

```js
// same script as above
$('.search-text').each(function(i, el) {
  let text = $(el).html();
  let highlights = $(el).attr("attribute").split(" ");
  for (str of highlights) {
    text = text.replace(str, '<span class="highlight-text">' + str + '</span>');
  }
  $(el).html(text);
})
```

```css
.highlight-text {
  background-color: #FFC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="search-text" attribute="span">Text AAA <span>test</span></span>
```

#### Starting with a string

If your starting point is an HTML string instead of an already-built DOM tree, all you need to do is convert that string into a document fragment first so you can use these DOM tools on it:

```
let fragment = $('<template>');
fragment.html($yourStringHere);
/* manipulate fragment contents as above, then */
return fragment.html();
```

Comment: Can you use a variable such as: $string = "<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span>
<span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text AAA</span> I"; and process this variable in order to replace the text instead of processing the DOM? In my example I have a string that contains the HTML and I want to replace it with a new string.

Comment: Sure, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A partial solution inspired by Daniel Beck's answer. This solution doesn't manipulate the DOM. (I just displayed the result on the DOM for demonstration purposes)

https://jsfiddle.net/mt2yz90L/3/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

JS:

```
  let searchedText = 'aa';
  let html ='<span class="whatever-class custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 1 AAA">AAA BBB</span><span class="search-text custom-class-name" attribute="Whatever 2 AAA">Text AAA</span> I';
  var htmlParts = html.split(/(<span class="search-text[^>]+>|<\/span>)/g);
  var htmlPartsIndex = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < htmlParts.length; i++) {
    if(htmlParts[i].indexOf('search-text') !== -1) {
        htmlPartsIndex = ++i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(htmlPartsIndex > 0) {
     htmlParts[htmlPartsIndex] = htmlParts[htmlPartsIndex].toLowerCase().replace(searchedText, '<span class="highlight-text">' + searchedText + '</span>')
  }
  $('#result').html(htmlParts.join(''));
```

CSS:

```
.highlight-text {
  background-color: red;
}
```

My only issue is that in my case (over 300 items to parse) it blocks the browser. So this is quite slow. I posted it in the idea that maybe someone will share a faster solution.